# Find component by display name when the component is stateless functional, with Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactjs, stateless, enzyme

I have the following components:

```
// Hello.js
export default (React) => ({name}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello {name ? name : 'Stranger'}!
    </div>
  )
}

// App.js
import createHello from './Hello'

export default (React) => () => {
  const Hello = createHello(React)
  const helloProps = {
    name: 'Jane'
  }
  return (
    <Hello { ...helloProps } />
  )
}

// index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import createApp from './App'

const App = createApp(React)

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

And I want to set up a test to see if the `App` component contains one `Hello` component. I tried the following, using [`Tape`](https://github.com/substack/tape) and [`Enzyme`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/):

```
import createApp from './App'
import React from 'react'
import test from 'tape'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

test('App component test', (assert) => {
  const App = createApp(React)
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
  assert.equal(wrapper.find('Hello').length === 1, true)
})
```

But the result was that the `length` property of the `find` result was equal to `0`, when I was expecting it to be equal to `1`. So, how do I find my `Hello` component?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do in this case. Enzyme can match component constructors based on the constructor's static `.displayName` or `.name` properties, or by referential equality. As a result, the following approaches should all work:

#### Direct Reference

you can import the actual components in your tests and find them using direct references to the component:

```
// NavBar-test.js

import NavBar from './path/to/NavBar';  
...  
wrapper.find(NavBar).length)
```

#### Named Function Expressions

If you use named function expressions to create your stateless functional components, the names should still work.

```
// NavBar.js  

module.exports = function NavBar(props) { ... }
```

#### Static `.displayName` property

You can add a static `.displayName` property on the components:

```
// NavBar.js

const NavBar = (props) => { ... };
NavBar.displayName = 'NavBar';
```

Comment: but what is the reason for such enzyme behavior? because there should not be difference between "named" and "default" exports. Enzyme doesnt find named exports and returns the default exported components when i provide static name string ```expect(wrapper.find('AComponent').length)...```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the `Hello` component in the top of your file and then update your assertion to find the actual component and not the name of it. Like below:

```
import createApp from './App'
import Hello from './Hello'
import React from 'react'
import test from 'tape'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

test('App component test', (assert) => {
  const App = createApp(React)
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
  assert.equal(wrapper.find(Hello).length === 1, true)
})
```

Btw for all the enzyme users out there the assertion would be something like:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Hello)).toHaveLength(1);
```